# OAuth2 RACK - based for both Sinatra and Rails Applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, oauth-2.0, rack

Is it possible to implement OAuth2 security code once in Rack and use it on both of a Sinatra & Rails Apps simultaneously??

I am relatively new to ruby development, however it seems to me that developing based on Rack is beneficial for such scenarios.

I am currently a fan of sinatra and thats the web framework I will use for my ruby development but I like to code following the best practices.

Please advise, if I want to develop OAuth2 code shared for all my sinatra applications and Rails applications. Is this technically possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, take a look at [Omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/) as an example.  Many of the providers like Facebook, Twitter, and Google (via [google-api-omniauth](http://rubygems.org/gems/google-api-omniauth)) use OAuth 2.0

Comment: how can i be a provider for OAuth2.0?? is this possible in Omniauth?

Comment: Omniauth is more for an oauth2 client. But there are other OAuth2 libraries for ruby for implementing providers. Haven't tried any of them, but something like https://github.com/nov/rack-oauth2/ might fit your needs.